# PHP: change page action of a form by url in select

Tags: php, jquery, forms

hy, i have a problem with a form. i know the question is simple but i can not have a solution. Well, this is my form:

```
<form id="search" method="post" action="cerca_redirect2.php" >

 <select id="tipo" name="tipo"class="chzn-select" style="width:165px;" tabindex="1"  >

 <option value="http://case.vortigo.it/vendita-immobili/index.php"> Vendita</option>
 <option value="http://case.vortigo.it/affitto-immobili/index.php">Affitto</option>

 </select>

      <input id="field" name="field" type="text" value=""/>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="" />
    </form>
```

my goal is when i select "Vendita" and i submit the form i have to go to the url in the select "Vendita", for each select. someone can help me? thanks

Comment: So you want some code to perform a redirect? ... or did I miss the question?

Answer (score 2):

In the server side php code, do something like this

```
if (isset($_POST['tipo']) && !empty($_POST['tipo']))
{
   header('Location: ' . $_POST['tipo']);
}
```

Note: This is a very basic version, you will want to ensure the url is valid by either maintaining a list of urls on the server, or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways, but you can for example use following:
See the onsubmit part in the form definition

```
<form id="search" method="post" action="cerca_redirect2.php" onsubmit="this.action=document.getElementById('tipo')[document.getElementById('tipo').selectedIndex].value" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the action of the form based on the select?  The following should be along the lines of what you want.

```
$('#tipo').on('change', function() {
    var newAction = this.val();
    $('#search').prop('action', newAction);
}
```

**UPDATE**

You will want to wrap this code in `$(document).ready()` so that the event will be registered after the DOM has been loaded.

Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tipo').on('change', function() {
        var newAction = this.val();
        $('#search').prop('action', newAction);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a perfect candidate for using `.prop()` over `.attr()`

Comment: Yes, changed answer to reflect that.

Comment: You are welcome, see updated answer for placing the code.  You would place the code in the head and wrapped in a `ready` function so that you know that all the DOM elements are rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If I understan your question correctly, you need a way to change the action value to the selected option's value

this is how to do that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tipo").on("change", function(){
        $("#search").attr("action", $(this).val());
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6ybMP/

Comment: thanks for answering, and sorry for my next stupid question; but where i have to put the javascript code? in the < head > ? because not working..

Comment: Well, your question had a "Jquery" tag, so I expected you to have jquery included. you would add the script in the head, but you hve to have jquery included in the head